# How can I open a window if my given conditions are true?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, login-system

I have something like a login system. So if the user is logging with the right username and password he is passed to my project(main.py). I used tkinter and have in my order I have two files: one is the logging system (`logging.py`) and one is my project `(main.py`). So I want to open my main, when the username and password are correct. (As you can in my main.py code see, it is an email storage)

I tried with:

```
import tkinter as tk
import main

def login():
    username = entry_username.get()
    passwort = entry_passwort.get()

    if username == "username" and passwort == "passwort123":
        main_window = tk.Toplevel(main) 
        main_window.mainloop()
```

But it does not work and I have no idea how can I open my main if the login is correct?

Complet code from logging.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import main


def login():
  username = entry_username.get()
  passwort = entry_passwort.get()

if username == "username" and passwort == "passwort123":
    main_window = tk.Toplevel(main)
    main_window.mainloop()



root = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

# FRAME 
frame_username = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
frame_username.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07,             
anchor="e")

frame_passwort = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
frame_passwort.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07,     
anchor="w")

frame_button = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame_button.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.13, relheight=0.11)


#  prints above the entry form mail " mail " and from passwort " password"
frame_username_text = tk.Frame(root)
frame_username_text.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.3, 
relheight=0.07, anchor="e")

frame_passwort_text = tk.Frame(root)
frame_passwort_text.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.3, 
relheight=0.07, anchor="w")

# ENTRY USERNAME / PASSWORT
entry_username = tk.Entry(frame_username)
entry_username.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

entry_passwort = tk.Entry(frame_passwort)
entry_passwort.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#Button
login_button = tk.Button(frame_button, text = "sign in", font=    
(8),bg="#33cc33", fg="white", command=login)
login_button.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)



#just assigns mail to mail and passwort to password

# EMAIL LABEL
label_username = tk.Label(frame_username_text, text = "Username", font=(10) 
)
label_username.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# PASSWORT LABEL
label_passwort = tk.Label(frame_passwort_text, text = "Passwort", font= 
(10))
label_passwort.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   pass


root.mainloop()
```

And here is my code from main.py :

```
import tkinter as tk


def save_info():
    mail = entry_mail.get()
    passwort = entry_passwort.get()
    entry_mail.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_passwort.delete(0, tk.END)

label_list["text"]=str(mail)+" | "+str(password)



root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

# EMAIL ENTRY
entry_mail = tk.Entry(root)
# entry_mail.insert(0,"Type your Mail...")
entry_mail.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="e")

# PASSWORT ENTRY
entry_passwort = tk.Entry(root)
entry_passwort.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="w")


# PASSWORT FRAME
frame_passwort = tk.Frame(root)
frame_passwort.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="w")

# EMAIL FRAME
frame_mail = tk.Frame(root)
frame_mail.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="e")

# BUTTON FRAME
frame_button = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
frame_button.place(relx=0.88, rely=0.165, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.07)

# LIST FRAME
frame_list = tk.Frame(root, bg="gray",bd=10)
frame_list.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.5, 
anchor="n")


# EMAIL LABEL
label_mail = tk.Label(frame_mail, text = "E-Mail")
label_mail.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# PASSWORT LABEL
label_passwort = tk.Label(frame_passwort, text = "Passwort")
label_passwort.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# LIST LABEL
label_list = tk.Label(frame_list, anchor="nw", justify="left" )
label_list.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)


# SAVE BUTTON
button_save = tk.Button(frame_button, text="save",command=save_info)
button_save.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isn't clear what's not working. What I can tell you is when `login()` ends your `main_window` variable is destroyed.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have

Comment: You're doing it exactly right. Have you verified that `username` and `paswort` are what you're assuming they are? My guess is that you're calling this before the user has a chance to enter any data. Also, FWIW, you shouldn't call `mainloop` again. You should call that exactly once in a normal tkinter app.

Comment: What should be wrong with my code  ?

Comment: There isnt any mistakes in our sight? Include more code, so we can see whats happening else where that causing this.

Comment: the other file too please

Comment: ok guys, here is my complete code

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you're creating two instances of `Tk`. A proper tkinter program should always create exactly one.

Comment: Replace one of the `Tk()` with `Toplevel()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several changes in your code and it works perfect (just some red lines in the terminal, but that's ok cause it doesn't actually make any sense). See :

Login.py code :

```
import tkinter as tk

username = ""
passwort = ""

def login():
  username = entry_username.get()
  passwort = entry_passwort.get()

  if username == "username" and passwort == "passwort123":
    import main
    toplevel = tk.Toplevel(main)
  
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

# FRAME 
frame_username = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
frame_username.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07,             
anchor="e")

frame_passwort = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
frame_passwort.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07,     
anchor="w")

frame_button = tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame_button.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.13, relheight=0.11)

#  prints above the entry form mail " mail " and from passwort " password"
frame_username_text = tk.Frame(root)
frame_username_text.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.3, 
relheight=0.07, anchor="e")

frame_passwort_text = tk.Frame(root)
frame_passwort_text.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.3, 
relheight=0.07, anchor="w")

# ENTRY USERNAME / PASSWORT
entry_username = tk.Entry(frame_username)
entry_username.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

entry_passwort = tk.Entry(frame_passwort)
entry_passwort.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#Button
login_button = tk.Button(frame_button, text = "sign in", font=    
(8),bg="#33cc33", fg="white", command=login)
login_button.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#just assigns mail to mail and passwort to password

# EMAIL LABEL
label_username = tk.Label(frame_username_text, text = "Username", font=(10) 
)
label_username.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# PASSWORT LABEL
label_passwort = tk.Label(frame_passwort_text, text = "Passwort", font= 
(10))
label_passwort.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   pass

root.mainloop()
```

The problem was TYPOS and yes you should import main after the condition.

main.py code :

```
import tkinter as tk

mail = ""
password = ""
    
def save_info():
    mail = entry_mail.get()
    passwort = entry_passwort.get()
    entry_mail.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_passwort.delete(0, tk.END)

#label_list = ["text"]=str(mail)+" | "+str(password)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

# EMAIL ENTRY
entry_mail = tk.Entry(root)
# entry_mail.insert(0,"Type your Mail...")
entry_mail.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="e")

# PASSWORT ENTRY
entry_passwort = tk.Entry(root)
entry_passwort.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="w")

# PASSWORT FRAME
frame_passwort = tk.Frame(root)
frame_passwort.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="w")

# EMAIL FRAME
frame_mail = tk.Frame(root)
frame_mail.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.07, 
anchor="e")

# BUTTON FRAME
frame_button = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow")
frame_button.place(relx=0.88, rely=0.165, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.07)

# LIST FRAME
frame_list = tk.Frame(root, bg="gray",bd=10)
frame_list.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.5, 
anchor="n")

# EMAIL LABEL
label_mail = tk.Label(frame_mail, text = "E-Mail")
label_mail.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# PASSWORT LABEL
label_passwort = tk.Label(frame_passwort, text = "Passwort")
label_passwort.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# LIST LABEL
label_list = tk.Label(frame_list, anchor="nw", justify="left" )
label_list.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# SAVE BUTTON
button_save = tk.Button(frame_button, text="save", command=save_info)
button_save.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

and yes..... there may be more mistakes as your code is unclear(imo) so this is what i understood and wrote.

Comment: What are those red lines in the terminal ?

Comment: thank u :)   but you forget to say in main.py code:   root = tk.Toplevel()                                               otherwise the code is correct ;)

Comment: OK my pleasure that I am helpful to someone :)